How to prove this specific series converges?
Call positive integer $n$ "good" if $n^{2022} \geq s^{2023}$, where $s$ is the product of all prime divisors of $n$. How to prove that the sum of reciprocals of all "good" numbers converges? (This problem is from mathematical contest in Russia that was held in 2023)
I tried some inequalities and estimations(that attempts gave nothing to get closer to the solution so it doesn't make any sense to publish these attempts), but I couldn't show this sum converges, but I am sure some estimation must be applied to this sum.

See if this solution is okay with you.

Let $n=p_1^{a_1}\dots p_k^{a_k}$ where $a_i\ge 2$ for all $i$.
Let us look at the good numbers that are divisible by $n$ and don't have anymore prime factors with exponent greater than $1$ and $v_{p_i}(n)=a_i$ for all $i $. They would be of the form $q_1\dots q_sn$ where $q_i \neq p_j$. Furthermore, $p_1^{2022a_1-2023}\dots p_k^{2022a_k-2023}\ge q_1\dots q_s$.
Define $n':=p_1^{2022a_1-2023}\dots p_k^{2022a_k-2023}$.
The sum of reciprocal of such numbers would be $$\frac{1}{n}\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{m-\mbox{squarefree}: p_i \nmid m\ \& m\le n'} \frac{1}{m}\bigg)\le \displaystyle \frac{1}{n}\sum_{m\le n'} \frac{1}{m}\le \frac{\log(n')+1}{n} \le \frac{2022(\log(n)+1)}{n}$$ as $n'\le n^{2022}$.
Therefore, the sum of reciprocal of all good numbers is lesser than
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n:a_i\ge 2 \forall i} \frac{2022(\log(n)+1)}{n}.$$
For large enough $n$, we can bound $\log(n)+1$ above by $n^{0.1}$, for example. Therefore, we just need to show that $$\displaystyle \sum_{n:a_i\ge 2 \forall i \ \& \mbox{large} } \frac{2022}{n^{0.9}}$$
converges. This can be shown using the Euler product formula to be
$$2022\prod_p (1+\frac{1}{p^{0.9}(p^{0.9}-1)}).$$
Now, to show that this infinite product is finite, we apply logarithm and see that $$\log(\prod_p (1+\frac{1}{p^{0.9}(p^{0.9}-1)}))\le \sum_p \frac{1}{p^{0.9}(p^{0.9}-1)},$$
which converges.

This approach looks right.  To clarify the opening a bit, it looks like you are associating every good number with its largest powerful divisor.  This allows you to partition the good numbers into separate sums for a fixed powerful divisor; the "good" property lets you control how large these subsums can get.  Once you have reduced it to a sum over powerful numbers it gets easy as we know powerful numbers are only slightly more dense than squares (by a constant factor).

Yes, indeed. I was unaware of what these special divisors were called. Squarefull/powerful divisors. I have indeed associated a good number with its largest powerful divisor and used it to partition the good numbers. Everything you said is correct.
